# Debugging in the absence of debuggers

Tags: javascript, debugging

Some of my users have reported an inability to log in with certain mobile devices, such as the Nintendo 3DS and PSP web browsers. Personally, I have a 3DS and been able to reproduce the issue... but I haven't a clue how to fix it.

Basically, all I can determine is that *something* is wrong with the AJAX code, which is causing the form to submit to the wrong place in the wrong format.

Now, in the past I had errors with Chrome (turned out to be [adware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739819/detecting-malware-added-advertisements-on-my-site)) which I was able to debug using the Developer Tools, looking at the error console, and getting the result from there.

But how would I do this for something that has no such debugging tools? It's not just game consoles, the Steam In-Game Browser is also unable to log in with my apparently faulty AJAX code.

What steps, if any, can I take to start getting to the bottom of these errors, without the use of built-in debugging tools?

Comment: Debug builds and alert boxes I suspect :-(

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when had to debug an app that wasn't working on an iPad where I didn't have access to a Mac to debug with. Without knowing anything about the browsers you've mentioned, I'm hoping this will provide some value:

1) Firebug Lite: https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite This is a Javascript version of Firefox's debugger that you can add to your webpage, and while not as full featured, can hopefully provide you some insight into the errors you are experiencing

2) Ye olde debug statements. Instead of alerting them, I typically append them to some container styled with `overflow:scroll` so I can easily read through them like a trace

Good luck!

Comment: Firebug Lite looks promising. When I get home from work I'll have to see if it works on the problem browsers :D